# How to create dictionary object and add data to it in painless elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-painless

I want to write a painless script which should return a dictionary.
Basically, If I relate it to java, I want an output of Dictionary< String, List >.

So, I need to declare a Map and List in painless.
Also, I need to add data to it (like map.add())

Can I have an example how would you declare a map and add data to it?

The examples at [painless] (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/6.7/painless-examples.html) does not cover this.

I am using v6.7

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it simply like this:

Create the document with an empty dictionary

```
PUT index/1
{
  "dict": {}
}
```

Update the document to fill the dictionary in parameter

```
POST index/_update/1
{
    "script" : {
        "source": "ctx._source.dict.putAll(params)",
        "lang": "painless",
        "params" : {
            "key1": ["val1", "val2", "val3"],
            "key2": ["val4", "val5"]
        }
    }
}
```

You can also index the document from scratch using a script (with [`scripted_upsert`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html#scripted_upsert))

```
POST index/_update/1
{
    "scripted_upsert":true,
    "script" : {
        "source": """
          ctx._source.dict = [:];
          ctx._source.dict['key1'] = params.key1;
          ctx._source.dict['key2'] = params.key2;
        """,
        "params" : {
            "key1" : ["val1", "val2", "val3"],
            "key2" : ["val1", "val2", "val3"]
        }
    },
    "upsert" : {}
}
```

In both cases, you'll end up with a document like this:

GET /index/1

```
{
  "dict": {
      "key1" : ["val1", "val2", "val3"],
      "key2" : ["val1", "val2", "val3"]
  }
}
```

Comment: This seems like a nice workaround of the requirement but i got stuck at one point. Earlier I was thinking to write a _search api and output the desired result. But now, if I have to write an update api, how can I possibly query index-A and document A1 and update the results to index-B document B1? If I mention index name(A) in the url, how can I update a document in index (B) ?

Comment: You need to do it with two requests

Comment: I found these docs helpful: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/master/painless-api-reference-shared-java-util.html